# Characterization of orthogonal projection.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let H be a hilbert space. Let $P \in B(H,H)$, $\|P\| = 1, P^2 = P$. Then there exists unique closed subspace $L$ such that $P = P_L$.

I am thinking that $L = Im(P)$ then it is a subspace. I think the reason it is closed because P above is a open map? I am not sure why.  I am not sure how to prove uniqueness either.

Comment: You also need $P=P^*$ in order for $P$ to be an orthogonal projection. There are lots of non-orthogonal projections $P$, meaning $P^2=P$ holds.

Comment: @TrialAndError $||P|| = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y\in \overline L$. Then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $Px_n\to y$. Now, since $P $ is bounded, 
$$
Py=P(\lim Px_n)=\lim P^2x_n=\lim Px_n=y,
$$
so $y=Py\in L$.

For the uniqueness, if $P=P_M$ then $P_L=P_M$, which implies that $M=L$. If you want to show this, let $m\in M$; then $$m=P_Mm=P_Lm\in L.$$So $M\subset L$. Similarly, $L\subset M$.

Comment: okay cool. That is very illuminating. Do we even need the condition that $||P|| = 1$ ? I mean you didn't use it anywhere in your proof.

Comment: Note that my argument shows uniqueness of the subspace. To conclude that two projections are equal when their ranges are equal,  you need them to be orthogonal.

Comment: I see that is cool. Thank you.